# Accessing member of base class

Tags: typescript

See the inheritance example from the playground on the TypeScript site:

```
class Animal {
  public name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  move(meters) {
    alert(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
  }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
  move() {
    alert("Slithering...");
    super.move(5);
  }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
  move() {
    alert(super.name + " is Galloping...");
    super.move(45);
  }
}

var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");

sam.move();
tom.move(34);
```

I have changed one line of code: the alert in `Horse.move()`. There I want to access `super.name`, but that returns just `undefined`. IntelliSense is suggesting that I can use it and TypeScript compiles fine, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Working example. Notes below.

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name) {
    }

    move(meters) {
        alert(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    move() {
        alert(this.name + " is Slithering...");
        super.move(5);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    move() {
        alert(this.name + " is Galloping...");
        super.move(45);
    }
}

var sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");

sam.move();
tom.move(34);
```

1. You don't need to manually assign the name to a public variable. Using `public name` in the constructor definition does this for you.
2. You don't need to call `super(name)` from the specialised classes.
3. Using `this.name` works.

Notes on use of `super`.

This is covered in more detail in [section 4.9.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.9.2) of the language specification.

The behaviour of the classes inheriting from `Animal` is not dissimilar to the behaviour in other languages. You need to specify the `super` keyword in order to avoid confusion between a specialised function and the base class function. For example, if you called `move()` or `this.move()` you would be dealing with the specialised `Snake` or `Horse` function, so using `super.move()` explicitly calls the base class function.

There is no confusion of properties, as they are the properties of the instance. There is no difference between `super.name` and `this.name` - there is simply `this.name`. Otherwise you could create a Horse that had different names depending on whether you were in the specialized class or the base class.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for the reference to the language specification. Are you aware of any documentation on why, for example, base class property accessors aren't virtualized and accessible via overriding accessors in the derived class (as methods are)?

Comment: Section 4.8 covers everything that has been written down to date - it tends to be a "this is the behaviour", though rather than a "this is why".

Comment: Thanks Steve Fenton. I also just stumbled upon a similar discussion here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/418349. Seems to be an imbalance in the language; my guess is the decision was made to keep the emitted JavaScript simple, as opposed to "work-around" helper methods to compensate for the lack of JavaScript support.

Answer (score 11):

You're using the keywords `super` and `this` incorrectly. Below is an example that demonstrates them being correctly.

```
    class Animal {
        public name: string;

        constructor(name: string) { 
            this.name = name;
        }

        move(meters: number) {
            console.log(this.name + " moved " + meters + "m.");
        }
    }
    
    class Horse extends Animal {
        move() {
            console.log(super.name + " is Galloping...");
            console.log(this.name + " is Galloping...");
         
            super.move(45);
        }
    }
    
    var tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");
    
    Animal.prototype.name = 'horseee'; 
    
    tom.move(34);
    // Outputs:
    
    // horseee is Galloping...
    // Tommy the Palomino is Galloping...
    // Tommy the Palomino moved 45m.
```

##### Explanation:

1. The first logs the dynamic value for `super.name` which is proceeded by the static string value `"is Galloping..."`. The keyword `this` references the **"prototype chain"** of the object `tom`, and not the object `tom` self. Because we have added a name property on the `Animal.prototype`, horse will be outputted.
2. The second log outputs `this.name`, the `this` keyword refers to the the tom object itself.
3. The third log is logged using the `move` method of the Animal base class. This method is called from Horse class move method with the syntax `super.move(45);`. Using the `super` keyword in this context will look for a `move` method on the prototype chain which is found on the Animal prototype.

Remember TS still uses prototypes under the hood and the `class` and `extends` keywords are just syntactic sugar over prototypical inheritance.