# Getter/Setter as function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create property getter/setter as a function?

Standard getter/setter work like following:

```
class Test {
  something: any;

  get prop() {
    return something;
  }
  set prop(value) {
    something = value;
  }
}

let instance = new Test();
instance.prop = 'Foo';
console.log(instance.prop); // = Foo
```

I would need following:

```
let instance = new Test();
instance.prop('Bar') = 'Foo'; // access setter as a function of prop
console.log(instance.prop('Bar')); // = Foo
```

Yes, I know it's unorthodox usage and yes, I know that I could implement this functionality bit differently. I'm just interested if this is possible in JS/TS/ES6.

**Update**

This is the closest I got:

```
class Test {
  something: any;

  prop(area /* my custom symbol type */) {
    const obj: any = {};
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'value', {
      // get child object of my complex object
      get: () => this.something[area];
      // replace part of my complex object
      set: (value) => {
        this.something = {...this.something, [area]: value}
      }
    });
  }
}

let instance = new Test();
instance.prop('Bar').value = 'Foo';
console.log(instance.prop('Bar').value); // = Foo
```

So in short, I'd like to get rid of `value` suffix if possible.

Comment: Since syntactically you *cannot* assign to a function call… no.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `instance['Bar'] = 'Foo'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 getter/setter with arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827519/es6-getter-setter-with-arrow-function)

Comment: Looks confusing... at least it has to be `instance.prop('Foo')` as a setter, `instance.prop()` - getter

Comment: Another way of doing this, similar to what FieryCat is saying, would be `instance.prop('Bar', 'Foo')` to set and `instance.prop('Bar')` to get.

Comment: @deceze: What I want is a getter function that takes an argument to say pre-filter or reduce the result. Of course this would be possible with getting everything first and filtering later. I was just wondering whether it could be possible to hide it behind a getter/setter.

Comment: @DanielMizerski: Unfortunately not

Comment: @MikeC, as mentioned my question was not how to do it differently, but rather is it possible to solve it this way.

Comment: @MiroslavJonas I know but as deceze said, what you want is not possible. I was merely presenting something that *is* possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @deceze mentioned in the first comment, it is not possible to assign to function call, so solution in the update is as best as it gets.