# Using arrow function with class get | Reducing code for defining class constants

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am trying to create constants in javascript. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647215/declaring-static-constants-in-es6-classes) helpful. Following that, I wrote something like this.

```
const ERR1 = 'Error 1',
  ERR2 = 'Error 2',
  ERR3 = 'Error 3',
  ERR4 = 'Error 4'

class Error {
  static get ERR1 () {
    return ERR1
  }

  static get ERR2 () {
    return ERR2
  }

  static get ERR3 () {
    return ERR3
  }

  static get ERR4 () {
    return ERR4
  }
}
```

Although this works perfectly, I want to reduce the code as it is quite verbose. Probably to one liners using arrow functions like this in class.

```
static get ERR1 = () => ERR1
static get ERR2 = () => ERR2
...
```

But, this gives error stating that `Unexpected token =`. Tried the same with `static get ERR1: () => ERR1` and same error `Unexpected token :`

To answer this question any one of this is sufficient.

- Why is this an error?
- Is it possible to write class get using arrow syntax?
- Is there any shorter way of defining constants?

Comment: The very answer you linked shows many ways to put constants on a `class`, including the use of the experimental class fields proposal syntax which beats everything in conciseness. And yes, you cannot use arrow functions with `get` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript syntax bans getters from being arrow functions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33827643/1358308 for more info)

I'd probably just do something like:

```
const Error = Object.freeze({
  ERR1: 'Error 1',
  ERR2: 'Error 2',
  ERR3: 'Error 3',
  ERR4: 'Error 4',
})
```

Comment: I actually want it to be as a class. There is also a constructor in Error, and some other methods as well.