# Angular2 - subscribe to Service variable changes

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an authentication service that makes the authenticated variable equal to true or false.

```
checkAuthentication(){
  this._authService.getAuthentication()
    .subscribe(value => this.authenticated = value);
}
```

How do I execute a function when `this.authenticated` has changed value? ngOnChanges is not picking up the change.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To keep `authenticated` in service and share it between components you can use 
[`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md), it's `value` to check authentication in different places, and it's `subscribe()` method to react on change...

```
class AuthService {
  public authenticated = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  getAuthentication() {
    this._http.get('/authenticate')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(json => Boolean(json)) // or whatever check you need...
      .subscribe((value: boolean) => this.authenticated.next(value))
  }
}

class Component {
  constuctor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    // Only check once even if component is 
    // destroyed and constructed again
    if (this._authService.authenticated.value === null)
      this._authService.getAuthentication();
  }

  onSubmit(){
    if (!this._authService.authenticated.value)
      throw new Error("You are authenticated!")
  }
}
```

> How do I execute a function when `this.authenticated` has changed value?

```
  this._authService.authenticated
   .subscribe((value: boolean) => console.log(value))
```

Comment: Hi @Sasxa so if I have e.g. 5 components. `home.component.ts`, `footer.component.ts`, `navbar.component.ts`, `x.component.ts`, and `user.component.ts`. Assuming these 5 components, and if I want to check for authenticated. I'll have to add inject the following: `constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {...}` to all my 5 components. Is this correct? and do a `ngOnInit` for all 5 components? Need some help to understand Angular2 authentication concept.

Comment: There are many options/choices.. It all depends on what you're doing. You can authenticate at every component, or at root component only. It's a complex topic,  you'll need to decide what's best for your app (;

Comment: could you point me to discussion/forum/blog/article on this topic?

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to be working with the most recent version of Angular 2. Anyone find any solutions?

Answer (score 11):

I think that you could leverage the get / set syntax of TypeScript to detect when your authenticated property of your service is updated:

```
  private _authenticated:Boolean = false;
  get authenticated():Boolean {
        return this._authenticated ;
  }
  set authenticated ( authenticated Boolean) {
    // Plugin some processing here
      this._ authenticated = authenticated;
  }
```

When assigning a value, the "set authenticated" block is called. For example with such code:

```
this.authenticated = true;
```

See this question for more details:

- [get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript)

That said you could also leverage an EventEmitter property in the service. When the authenticated property is updated, the corresponding event could be fired.

```
export class AuthService {
  authenticatedChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor() {}

  emit(authenticated) {
    this.authenticatedChange.next(authenticated);
  }

  subscribe(component, callback) {
    // set 'this' to component when callback is called
    return this.authenticatedChange.subscribe(data => {
      callback(component, data);
    });
  }
}
```

See this link for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-in-angular2/34402436)

Comment: Is it good approach to go with, as you are suggesting to fire up some event on while setting `authenticated` value? Ideally setter are responsible for setting up value by manipulating the provided input value to its function..

Comment: Hi Thierry, I searched Angular.io site for documentation/tutorial on EventEmitter. But it was quite limited. Any idea where I can find guided tutorial on using Angular2 EventEmitter?

Comment: this is considered bad practice. recommended approach is to use Subject/BehaviorSubject

Comment: @atsituab you're definitely right. I answered this a long time ago ;-) I updated my answer accordingly! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who needs to handle the event. If it's the parent component, you can leverage output event bindings:

```
@Output authenticationChange: EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter();
checkAuthentication(){
     this._authService.getAuthentication()
     .subscribe(value => 
           if(value != this.authenticated) {
               this.authenticated = value);
               this.authenticationChange.emit(value);
      });
 }
```

And in your parent component:

```
 <directive (authenticationChange)="doSomething()">
```

Answer (score -2):

I used a `{{ showValue() }}` in the component template, and in the .ts file I called the service's variable

```
showValue() {
   this.authenticated = this._authService.authenticated;
   return "dummy"
}
```

Thanks to Angular2's GUI 2-way binding, it works.