# In Angular2, use inheritance or inject dependency?

Tags: angular, typescript, service

In angular2, suppose I have a `Parent` class and a `Child1` class, they have the same properties/members and methods. How to initialize the `Child1` class?

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class Parent {  
    constructor(
        private currentImg: string,
        private catImg: string,
        private dogImg: string,
        private enable: boolean) {
    }

    onMouseOver() {
        enable = true;
        currentImg = catImg;
    }

    onMouseClick() {
        enable = false;
        currentImg = dogImg;
    }

}
```

One of the child class want to extends `Parent` class:

```
import {Parent} from "./Parent";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/child.html',
    providers: [Parent]
})

export class Child1 {

     private currentImg: string = "img/dog.png",
     private catImg: string = "img/cat.png",
     private dogImg: string = "img/dog.png",
     private enable: false

    constructor(private _parent: Parent) {
    }

    onMouseOver() {
        this._parent.onMouseOver();
    }

    onMouseClick() {
        this._parent.onMouseClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize how? You want to set `Parent`'s properties that have the same name to `Child1`?

Comment: Yep, Parent and Child have the same properties name. Right now, when call the function of Child1 class, for example, onMouseOver() {
        this._parent.onMouseOver();
    }, it only changes the value of currentImg and enable of Parent Properties. But I want to change those properties value of Child class. Do you know how can I do?

Comment: You want that without inheritance (`Child1 extends Parent` clause)? Or you didn't know about it?

Comment: You can [inject non-classes values](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMSbAAL6rplTldAOP8tW?p=preview) into the constructor,  but it's a little bit annoying to define through provider each one of them.

Comment: I don't know how to use inheritance in anuglar2. In Java, we can use extends. But here, I was told to use inject dependency to realize inheritance. I am very confused about what should I do. Do you know have to use inheritance in angular2 based on my example?

Comment: You just have to use `extends` and call `super()` from the constructor, and classes will inherit base class methods and properties that you can use or overwrite when you need. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you extend a class main class can use base class' methods and properties.

```
export class Base {  
    private image: string = "img/dog.png"; // default image
    // you don't need catImg and dogImg here...
    // private catImg: string;
    // private dogImg: string;
    private currentImg: string;
    private enable: boolean;

    constructor() { }

    onMouseOver(image) {
        enable = true;
        currentImg = image;
    }

    onMouseClick(image) {
        enable = false;
        currentImg = image;
    }

}
```

When you want to set properties in your main class, you *don't* initialize/set value to them in the base class. **You only need to declare those properties and methods that you are using in `Base` class.** You can set common properties that classes will share, like default `image`, for example.

This is how you would extend Base class in two different classes:

```
import {Base} from "./Base";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<button (click)="onMouseClick(image)">show cat</button>`,
    providers: []
})
export class CatImage extends Base {

    private image: string = "img/cat.png",
    constructor() { 
      super();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<button (click)="onMouseClick(image)">show dog</button>`,
    providers: []
})
export class DogImage extends Base {

    private image: string = "img/dog.png",
    constructor() { 
      super();
    }
}
```

Both `CatImage` and `DogImage` will inherit `enable`, `currentImg` properties, `onMouseOver()` and `onMouseClick()` methods from Base class, and you can use them in their code/templates...

Comment: Very nice answer. May I ask if I have this file `auth0.service.ts` for authentication. Do I use it like this `export class CatImage extends Auth0Service {...}` and `export class DogImage extends Auth0Service {...}` so I can use the method in `auth0.service.ts` for example `.isLoggedIn();`

Comment: No, you extend a class when you want to change or, well, extend it's functionality (: To use a service you would inject it in constructor, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35540743/1876949)...

Comment: Great! Thanks @Sasxa

Comment: @Sasxa Have you deleted plunk code example? I have a question, if I don't want to pass parameter through functions like onMouseOver(image) because I have multiple parameters to pass, how should I do? Right now, I declared all the same properties as public in both child and parent, so that I can write function without parameter onMouseOver(), but I know declared properties as public is very unsafe.