# What is multi provider in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I understand that provider is for getting service from another class but what is multi-provider and token thing?

And also when we do `multi=true` ?

```
provide(NG_VALIDATORS, { useExisting: class),    multi: true })
```

Answer (score 67):

`multi: true` means that one provider token provides an array of elements. For example all directives for router support `routerLink`, `router-outlet` are provided by `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`.
If a new provider is registered with the token `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, then it overrides the previously registered directives. If `multi: true` (on the first registered **and** the new provider) is set, the new directives are added to the previously registered directives instead of overriding.

When `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` is injected (`constructor(@Inject(ROUTER_DIRECTIVES) directives) {}`) an array of directive instances is injected. It usually doesn't make sense to inject `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`. I used it just as an example because it is `multi: true`.

Comment: Could you give an example of when it would be usefull por favor

Comment: See the example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033835/angularjs2-preload-server-configuration-before-the-application-starts/39033958#39033958 where multiple factory functions can be provided under `APP_INITIALIZERS` and Angular will call each of them (in the sequence they were provided) and waits for the returned `Promise`.

Comment: `NG_VALIDATORS` as an example. They are: `required, min, max, email...`

Comment: This can be relevant examples for **multi: true**

`providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptorService, multi: true  } ]`

Comment: If multi: false provider is provided by component, will it override previous providers for same token for subtree of components under it or globally?

Comment: @blazkovicz For components under it is my guess, but you'd need to verify yourself to be sure.

Answer (score 12):

Using `multi: true` tells Angular that the provider is a multi provider. As mentioned earlier, with multi providers, we can provide multiple values for a single token in DI.

**Usages:**

If we have a couple of directives that should automatically be available in our entire application without anyone having to define them in component decorations, we can do that by taking advantage of multi providers and extending what is being injected for `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`.

```
@Directive(...)
class Draggable { }

@Directive(...)
class Morphable { }

@Component(...)
class RootCmp { }
```

and

```
// at bootstrap
bootstrap(RooCmp, [
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: Draggable, multi: true}),
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: Morphable, multi: true})
]);
```

[Details](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: what does it mean provide multiple values for single token in DI

Comment: See example code. Injecting an array of directives/values in code .the detail link has examples and explanation

Comment: What does it mean if function declared like this : private get isReverse() what is get keyword

Comment: It is property syntax of typescript see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript

Comment: you registers your services to a token Service provider (ex: NG_VALIDATORS) for events. Observer uses the token service to get all registers service pass events to them (ex: Form will get all services from NG_VALIDATORS  then pass event to all validations)

Answer (score 12):

**What is a multi-provider?**

Provider is defined here.

https://angular.io/api/core/Provider

Basically, the provider describes how an injector is configured. So a multi-provider is you using multiple providers instead of a single provider, for instance

```
providers: [
 { provide: TOKEN1 , useClass: ClassName1},

 { provide: TOKEN2 , useClass: ClassName2}
]
```

In the above scenario, instances of both classes are created for the given token. This is then available for dependency injection (In the constructors of the particular classes.)

---

**What is Token?**

Token is the lookup key for locating the dependency value, for instance let’s take as follows…

then the lookup key is the TYPE of className, and the dependency value is the INSTANCE of its class.

```
providers: [ClassName]
```

In the following example, the TOKEN1, and TOKEN2 are the lookup keys, and the dependency values are the instance of both classes.

```
providers: [
 { provide: TOKEN1 , useClass: ClassName1},

 { provide: TOKEN2 , useClass: ClassName2}
]
```

---

**When do we use multi=true ?**

The multi is useful when you register multiple providers for the same token. Let’s say in the following example, then the last provider is injected because it’s used at the end, meaning

you won’t be able to use a ClassName1 instance. So what you can do is to use multi=true, and this signals Angular to register multiple providers for the SAME token. So this injects an ARRAY of values.

What is the value? the value is the INSTANCE of the classes.

```
providers: [
 { provide: TOKEN , useClass: ClassName1},

 { provide: TOKEN , useClass: ClassName2}
]
```

So the rule of thumb is if you are registering multiple providers for the same TOKEN then always use multi=true to avoid the first provider from not being injected. When it's injected, you can use it in the constructor of the class.

*NOTE: I am not an expert in this area. So if you saw any problem please let me know.*

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Creates multiple providers matching the same token (a multi-provider).
>   Multi-providers are used for creating pluggable service, where the
>   system comes with some default providers, and the user can register
>   additional providers. The combination of the default providers and the
>   additional providers will be used to drive the behavior of the system.

[Source](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Provider-class.html)