# What does multi:true mean in providers in angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient, angular-providers

I am using `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in angular4. For this, I have created `HttpServiceInterceptor` class that implements `HttpInterceptor` interface and provide the defintion for `intercept` method. Then registered provider for `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` like this

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: HttpServiceInterceptor,
    multi: true
}],
```

and this is working fine. But still I don't understand what does `multi:true` mean here? I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144889/2172547).

If I remove `multi:true` option then there is an error on browser side

```
Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Mixing multi and non multi provider is not possible for token InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
    at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.webpackJsonp.487.NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (vendor.js:36335)
    at NgModuleCompiler.webpackJsonp.487.NgModuleCompiler.compile (vendor.js:43184)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.487.JitCompiler._compileModule (vendor.js:51527)
    at vendor.js:51472
    at Object.then (vendor.js:26354)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.487.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:51470)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.487.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.js:51399)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.0.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (vendor.js:4746)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.0.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (vendor.js:4732)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:23366)
```

Does this mean `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` is multi-provider that initializes multiple directives or components? If so then what are other directives and components?

Comment: Multi-provider doesn't have anything to do with directives or components. The cited answer mentions directives only as an example.

Comment: so according to the answer HTTP_INTERCEPTOR is a token thatprovide multiple directives, registering new provider will override other registered providers?

Comment: It provides multiple values per token. Again, it has nothing to do with directives.

Comment: An interceptor is not a directive or a component. providers provide instances of **services**. When multi is used, the provider allows *adding* a service to an array of services (here, interceptors) registered for a given token. So HttpClient will get an array of interceptors, that will be called in chain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multi-providers have nothing to do with directives. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144889/2172547) mentions directives only as an example.

Considering that `FOO` is injection token, this

```
providers: [
  { provide: FOO, useClass: Bar, multi: true },
  { provide: FOO, useClass: Baz, multi: true }
]
```

makes `FOO` injected dependency an array of multiple providers that were assigned to this token, i.e. is same thing as:

```
providers: [
  { provide: FOO, useValue: [Bar, Baz] }
]
```

The difference is that multi-providers can be defined in multiple places on same injector, and all additional `{ provide: FOO, multi: true, ... }` do a `push` to `FOO` array.