# The get format statement in angular 2 example

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In the angular 2 examples for pipe: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html
there is an example of HeroBirthday2Component. I am not able to understand how this line works

`get format()   { return this.toggle ? 'shortDate' : 'fullDate'; }`

I mean I understand that it toggles the format property and the DOM gets updated with the change detection after toggleFormat() changes it. But I am not able to grasp the line above. Could some one please explain the code line and its implementation.

Comment: What don't you understand, the `return this.toggle ? 'shortDate' : 'fullDate';` part?

Comment: no the get statement.. I don't see any calls for a function named get or format() or is get a keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a getter, just like in other strongly typed languages.

See here:

[get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript)

Comment: ohh ok. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Let me know if there's any more information you need to accept the answer.

Comment: yeah it needs few seconds before I can. but I will

Comment: Thanks @Pawan!  best of luck with your development.