# Typescript: why is get necessary in this case?

Tags: typescript, getter-setter

I'm following [this auth0 tutorial.](https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-2/) In this particular service, only one method has get in front of it.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript) and some tutorials, but it really didn't clarify anything in this particular case.

As I understand it, getters go along with setters, so you can prevent modification of some class member, as in:

```
Class Whatever{

// don't modify the original, only the instance members
private myNum: Number; 

//set the instance member
set myNum(aNum:Number){ 
   this.myNum = aNum;
}

//and now you can get it
get myNum(){
 return this.myNum
}

}
```

But I have searched through the entire tutorial, and couldn't find an explanation for this getter. Anyway, here's the code (**it's the last method, tokenValid():**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // Create Auth0 web auth instance
  private _auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_ID,
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_DOMAIN,
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.REDIRECT,
    audience: AUTH_CONFIG.AUDIENCE,
    scope: AUTH_CONFIG.SCOPE
  });
  userProfile: any;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  // Create a stream of logged in status to communicate throughout app
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.loggedIn);

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // If authenticated, set local profile property
    // and update login status subject.
    // If not authenticated but there are still items
    // in localStorage, log out.
    const lsProfile = localStorage.getItem('profile');

    if (this.tokenValid) {
      this.userProfile = JSON.parse(lsProfile);
       this.isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin') === 'true';
      this.setLoggedIn(true);
    } else if (!this.tokenValid && lsProfile) {
      this.logout();
    }
  }

  setLoggedIn(value: boolean) {
    // Update login status subject
    this.loggedIn$.next(value);
    this.loggedIn = value;
  }

  login() {
    // Auth0 authorize request
    this._auth0.authorize();
  }

  handleAuth() {
    // When Auth0 hash parsed, get profile
    this._auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this._getProfile(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        console.error(`Error authenticating: ${err.error}`);
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }

  private _getProfile(authResult) {
    // Use access token to retrieve user's profile and set session
    this._auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err, profile) => {
      if (profile) {
        this._setSession(authResult, profile);
      } else if (err) {
        console.error(`Error authenticating: ${err.error}`);
      }
    });
  }

  private _setSession(authResult, profile) {
    // Save session data and update login status subject
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + Date.now());
    // Set tokens and expiration in localStorage and props
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
    this.userProfile = profile;
    // Update login status in loggedIn$ stream

    this.isAdmin = this._checkAdmin(profile);
        localStorage.setItem('isAdmin', this.isAdmin.toString());
    this.setLoggedIn(true);
  }

  private _checkAdmin(profile) {
      // Check if the user has admin role
      const roles = profile[AUTH_CONFIG.NAMESPACE] || [];
      return roles.indexOf('admin') > -1;
    }


  logout() {
    // Ensure all auth items removed from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
    localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
    localStorage.removeItem('authRedirect');
     localStorage.removeItem('isAdmin');
    // Reset local properties, update loggedIn$ stream
    this.userProfile = undefined;
     this.isAdmin = undefined;
    this.setLoggedIn(false);
    // Return to homepage
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

/////////HERE IT IS

      get tokenValid(): boolean {
        // Check if current time is past access token's expiration
        const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
        return Date.now() < expiresAt;
  }

}
```

Comment: What makes you believe it's *necessary*? You can write getters simply as a stylistic choice. The method could have been `isTokenValid()` or whatever

Comment: It just seems very specific that the coder chose to use it with only one method, the last one after plenty of others. Didn't occur to me as a stylistic choice. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice there is no setter. Creating a getter without a setter is a good way to have a read-only property that's safe from outside modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 properties with same name.
So you can use underscore for private members.

```
class Whatever {

  constructor(private _myNum: Number) {
  }

  set myNum(aNum: Number) {
    this._myNum = aNum;
  }

  get myNum() {
    return this._myNum
  }
}
```

If you will need to use descendant class for Whatever,
and will need to overwrite one method (get or set), you will need to
overwrite both.

Take a look how it is working in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty