# Dynamically hide / show tooltip in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some elements inside `ngFor` loop. Some of them have tooltips while others don't. When I use the following code like this:

```
<div ngFor="let item of items">
    <div [title]="item.title">
```

items that don't have tooltips will show `undefined`. Is there a way to hide it if the item doesn't have one while other items' tooltips still get to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `||` operator to set the default value as an empty string if `item.title` is not defined. This will prevent the tooltip from being displayed. An example is shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-musdce).

```
<div [title]="item.title || ''"> Some content </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would just add another couple approachs, in case you weren't aware, you can also do this:

```
<div [title]="getTitle()"> Some content </div>
```

Then in your typescript:

```
public getTitle(): string{
   return item.title || '';
}
```

---

Alternatively to this, you could take advantage of typescript [getter/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript):

```
export class Item{
  private _title:string;
  get title():string {
      return this._title || '';
  }
  set title(value:string) {
      this._title = value;
  }
}
```

This way, title will never return `null` or `undefined`.