# Mapping JSON String/JS object to Typescript class with private attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

This is a typescript class with an exposed but not editable attribute:

```
export class Category {

    private _id: number;

    constructor(id: number){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public get id(){
        return this._id;
    }

}
```

I would like to map it from a JSON like this:

```
{ id: 1 }
```

There are some obvious problems here:

- I know that "_id" can't be magically mapped to "id" so maybe I could implement a custom logic that renames all the attributes with a _ before the name
- I would like to keep the constructor with the id param but maybe I'm not able to map an object who require arguments before instantiation
- With an empty constructor, I tried `Object.assign(new Category(), jsonObject)`, however, this does not work since `Cannot set property id of #<Category> which has only a getter`

What I want to avoid is to write custom mapping logic for every class like this with private attributes, I tried some other solutions and libraries but didn't work for my situation, they're all referencing to class with only public attributes

I don't even know if what I ask is achievable, so if the case it isn't, then I will "surrender" to use the class with only public attributes

Comment: Why that getter/setter? Wjy not just `readonly id: number;` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms well i was just following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript, why i should use readonly instead?

Comment: Can't you just pass the JSON via constructor instead of just the id?

Comment: @digorydoo since i can have only one constructor per class, i should write a static method for every class to be instantiated in the "normal" way, i would like to preserve the common instantiation with params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the object through constructor:

```
export class Category {
    private _a: number;
    private _b: string;
    constructor(values: { a: number; b: string }){
        this._a = values.a;
        this._b = values.b;
    }
    public getA() { return this._a; }
    public getB() { return this._b; }
}
```

You can still call it with or without JSON:

```
let cat1 = Category (values: { a: 42, b: 'hello' });

let json = '{"a":42,"b":"hello"}'
let cat2 = Category (values: JSON.parse (json));
```

Alternatively, keep the values in an object rather than a direct member. This makes it unnecessary to map the object to member variables:

```
export class Category {
    private _values: {
        a: number;
        b: string;
    }
    constructor(values: { a: number; b: string }){
        this._values = values;
    }
    public getA() { return this._values.a; }
    public getB() { return this._values.b; }
}
```

If you want to keep the old constructor, you can do so like this:

```
export class Category {
    private _values: {
        a: number;
        b: string;
    }
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {
        this._values = { a: a, b: b };
    }
    public static make (values: { a: number; b: string }) {
        this._values = values;
    }
    public getA() { return this._values.a; }
    public getB() { return this._values.b; }
}
```

Comment: Many interesting ideas, this would involve writing logic for every class but I guess that i not have other choices

Answer (score 2):

The missconception here is that you need a getter/setter at all just to manage visibility. You can't prevent code from accessing and modifying `id`, no matter what you do. You can however tell the IDE (and the developer using it) that he can only read/get the property by using the `readonly` modifier, which simplifies your code to:

```
 export class Category {
   readonly id: number;
 }
```

Noe that `readonly` thing only exists at compile time, and doesnt have any affects at runtime. Your IDE will prevent you from doing:

```
 (new Category).id = 5;
```

But it allows you to easily do:

```
 const category = Object.assign(new Category, { id: 5 });
```

Comment: There's a subtle difference between private and readonly, with readonly i can assing value only once in the constructor, this means that i'm not able to edit that attribute anymore after instantiation, i want to keep it editable in the class, in short words i would like to keep the "private attribute" concept here

Comment: @tizio in that case you could bypass the modifier `(this as any).id = 5;`