# TypeScript equivalent to static{ } in Java

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I want to call a method automatically when a TS class is accessed, similar to java's `static{ }`.

For example, if I implement a constants class in Java:

```java
public class Constants
{
    public static final String FOO;

    static
    {
        // ... creates a http request ...

        FOO = // ... gets "http:/.../api/foo" from server
    }
}
```

How can I implement something like this in TypeScript?

Currently, I'm using:

```
export class Constants
{
    public static FOO;

    public static ensureInitialized(callback)
    {
        if (this.FOO == null)
        {
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (request.readyState == 4)
                {
                    FOO = request.responseText;
                    callback();
                }
            };
            request.open('POST', "http:/.../api/foo", true);
            request.send('');
        }
        else callback();
    }
}
```

But that requires an active call to `ensureInitialized()` to all the methods using this constant. Are there any TS equivalent to `static{ }` in Java?

Comment: There's no direct equivalent that I can find but you could probably "fake it" using a property getter (examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should try to learn the TypeScript language and write idiomatic code. Many programmers come to TypeScript under the mistaken impression that the addition of static typing by TypeScript turns JavaScript into Java when nothing could be further from the truth. In order to use TypeScript effectively, you must understand JavaScript.

One can learn JavaScript very well from learning TypeScript, but only when understanding that TypeScript ***does not*** add any of the following:

- classical object oriented programming patterns
- nominal typing
- runtime type information

In idiomatic TypeScript/JavaScript, such an approach would make no sense since the same behavior can be concisely and elegantly achieved, while the idea of a static initializer on a class is borderline incoherent.

Here is a revised version

```
let foo: string | undefined;

export const Constants = {
    get FOO() {
        if (!foo) {
            fetch("http:/.../api/foo", { method: "POST" })
                .then(response => foo = response.text())
                .catch(console.error);
        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Advantages include brevity, encapsulation, and having people understand what you are doing via recognition of an idiom.

Note: *There is a problem of asynchronous lazy initialization that this answer does not attempt to address since it is out of scope.*

Answer (score 1):

Normally we are expecting to execute static upfront before even using that value

```
export class Constants {
  static foo: any;
  static __static_initialized: boolean = false;
  static __static_initialize() {
    if (Constants.__static_initialized) { return; }
    Constants.__static_initialized = true;
    fetch("http:/.../api/foo", { method: "POST" })
      .then(response => Constants.foo = response.text())
      .catch(console.error);
  }
}
Constants.__static_initialize();
```