# Typescript class level get and set methods

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a model that I can reuse throughout my application which is based heavily off of Eloquents model but not with as many features as this is only the frontend.

I have hit a bit of block though currently.

I am storing all of my data for the `Resource` inside of an `attributes` property which is initialised at the top of the class as an empty object. The reason I store it in an attributes property is the class is dynamic so it makes more sense to do it inside of this property.

However this has a bit of a fallback which I don't know if I can avoid... When I instantiate a new class which extends this `Resource` like the following...

```
const user: IUser = new User({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
});
```

I want to be able to then query them attributes directly from the user without having to go through the `attributes` property so I would like to type `user.firstName` rather than `user.attributes.firstName`.

I know in php you can do something like `__get()` but I don't believe there's magic methods within Typescript so I don't know if this is even achievable.

The basic class looks something like this...

```
export class Resource {
   attributes!: Attributes;

   constructor(attributes: Attributes = {}) {
       this.attributes = attributes;
   }
}
```

```
export class User extends Resource {
    //
}
```

EDIT: Current solution

After having a bit of a play around with the constructor of the `Resource` class I have come up with the following...

```
constructor(attributes: Attributes = {}) {
    Object.keys(attributes).forEach((attributeKey: string) => {
        Object.defineProperty(this, attributeKey, {
            get: () => this.getAttribute(attributeKey),
            set: (value: any) => this.setAttribute(attributeKey, value)
        });
    });
}
```

This seems to work perfectly, however when targeting a property on that class for example `user.firstName` it doesn't exist as that is an instance of User and as this class is dynamic it seems like an impossible task to be able to actually assign a type to this, I could make a resource interface which all interfaces extends, would this do the trick?

```
interface IUser extends IResource {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have managed to do something a little different so I will update the question...

Comment: Looks like it's duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko I have updated the question, it is not a duplicate

Comment: Do you have any logic in `Resource` class or it's just a model?

Comment: @VitaliiIlchenko The `Resource` class does have logic in yes, the example is just in the basic form. The attributes have getters and setters as inside of the Child Resource I am then able to create methods which will alter this attribute, for example `getFirstNameAttribute()` and in here I can add logic that always uppercases the first character and the getter will call this method.