# TypeScript This expression is not callable

Tags: typescript

I'm sure this is simple code, but I run into weird error but has no answer to.
I did also look up the answer from this: [get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript)

But my code is exact same thing. But I have this error when I set the instance's property:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures
```

This is my code

```js
/**
 * Class that use underscore name and get set syntax
 */
class Person {

    // can give any property name, use convention `_`
    private _fname: string;
    private _lname: string;

    constructor(first: string, last: string) {
        this._fname = first;
        this._lname = last;
    }

    public get firstname(): string {
        return this._fname;
    }

    public set firstname(first: string) {
        this._fname = first;
    }

    public get lastname(): string {
        return this._lname;
    }

    public set lastname(last: string) {
        this._lname = last;
    }

}

// create instance
let character = new Person("Laila", "Law-Giver");
console.log(`Jarl of Riften is ${character.firstname} ${character.lastname}`);

character.firstname("Saerlund");
console.log(`${character.firstname} ${character.lastname} is her son, who sides with the Empire.`);
```

I have error on `character.firstname("Saerlund");`

What does this mean? I don't see what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You've defined it as a setter, so use it as a property: `character.firstname = "name"`

Comment: As a self taugh / newbie, I really appreciate this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You declared `firstname` as a setter and in order to assign a new value to it you should do as follows:

```
character.firstname = "Saerlund";
```

Comment: As a self taugh / newbie, I really appreciate this. Thank you!