# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web TypeScript EcmaScript version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, visual-studio-express, ecmascript-5, compiler-flags

Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web TypeScript EcmaScript version

I simply want to change the version of EcmaScript from ES3 to ES5 in my TypeScript project. Is there a setting in a dropdown somewhere? The purpose of this is so that I may use the 'get' and 'set' keywords without a compile error and gain ES5 compliance. Alternatively, is there somewhere I can set a compiler flag? That would also be fine if I can send '--target ES5' but I can't find anything in this hunk of carp.

Comment: Did you even look at the question ? It says explicitly "I would like to use get/set syntax in TypeScript within Visual Studio Express for Web".  I didn't flag your question as a duplicate just because I didn't want to offend you - And now you downvote me ? The asnwer I gave you targets Visual Studio Express for Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems like a duplicate of: [Targeting ES5 with TypeScript in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811034/targeting-es5-with-typescript-in-visual-studio)

You can use the compiler flag -target ES5 to compile typescript to ecmascript 5. In VisualStudio this is possible by editing the xml file which stores the compiler target.

edit

Comment: Does Express not support csproj files?  Maybe you could elaborate on why that answer isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the Microsoft Extension for type script :
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34790